# The vertical line of ".slds-timeline__media:before" does not appear when using Activity Timeline on Lightning Component Tab page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

The vertical line of ".slds-timeline__media:before" does not appear when using Activity Timeline on Lightning Component Tab page.

```
<aura:component> 
    <ul> 
        <li> 
            <div class="slds-timeline__item"> 
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Call</span> 
                <div class="slds-media"> 
                    <div class="slds-media__body"> 
                        <div class="slds-media slds-media--timeline slds-timeline__media--call"> 
                            <div class="slds-media__figure slds-timeline__icon"> 
                                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" size="small"/> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="slds-media__body"> 
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="test">Log a Call Test</p> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <div class="slds-timeline__item"> 
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Call</span> 
                <div class="slds-media"> 
                    <div class="slds-media__body"> 
                        <div class="slds-media slds-media--timeline slds-timeline__media--task"> 
                            <div class="slds-media__figure slds-timeline__icon"> 
                                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:task" size="small"/> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="slds-media__body"> 
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="test">Create Task</p> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </li>        
    </ul> 
</aura:component>
```

[image]

On searching, I found that this is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAbaQAG). Does anybody have any workarounds so I can manage to get the vertical line?

> Update

This is happening when I am using `<lightning:card>`. When I am using `<lightning:card>` the vertical line disappears.  Here is the difference.

**Without `<lightning:card>`**

[image]

**With `<lightning:card>`**

[image]

Comment: It's weird I can't reproduce the bug. I added the component to a lightning component tab as the Known Issue link said. I have the vertical line displayed though. Where did you put yours?

Comment: I tried both in a Sandbox and Developer Edition Org, in both places it is not working.

Comment: Where did you put your component? It looks like you didn't add it to a tab. You didn't implement the right interface.

Comment: @MartinLezer I have found the exact scenario when it is not working. Please let me know if you know any work around.